# How to use two bars that are diferent variables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGfoJ.png)

And what I want to do is a side-by-side bar plot using ggplot function.

So far, I got this:

```
data1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Countries)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = A2004),width=.5, position='dodge', stat='identity', fill = "blue") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = A2018),width=.5, position='dodge', stat='identity', fill = "red")
```

But what I got was
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EHot.png)

How can I put the bars for A2004 and A2018 side-by-side and not inside one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to pivot your data into long format and map the fill aesthetic to the resulting names column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Countries, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data taken from image in question**

```r
data1 <- data.frame(Countries = c("SI - Eslovenia", "Gr - Grecia", 
                                  "CZ - Republica Checa"),
                    A2004 = c(2.9, 3, 2.9),
                    A2018 = c(4, 4.2, 2.6))

data1
#>              Countries A2004 A2018
#> 1       SI - Eslovenia   2.9   4.0
#> 2          Gr - Grecia   3.0   4.2
#> 3 CZ - Republica Checa   2.9   2.6
```